# Play Video from Memory stream or Byte Array in c# windows application using VLC player or WMP

Tags: c#, .net, video, libvlc

Am trying to play video from memory such as from byte array or memory stream but not able to find any solution. Am looking for solution similar to [BoxedApp](http://www.boxedapp.com/encrypted_video_streaming.html) which decrypt video in memmory using virtual file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media APIs, Media Foundation and DirectShow, allow building flexible pipelines sourcing from customized sources such as streams. You are, however, expected to implement custom components and embed them into pipeline (typically in native code domain, not managed) and then build playback UI on top of that.

If you prefer to to use pre-built players such as Windows Media Player or VLC, you are limited to sources these players could recognize, and this does not include in-memory streams (not to mention process boundaries for memory streams).